# How do I use log.debug in a .py file in django?

Tags: python, django

I have

```
log.debug("variable %s" % variable)
```

in a `.py` file in Django.

When I went to run it in the debugger in Textwrangler by clicking on #! --> Run in Terminal, I couldn't get the log.debug output to show up.

I'm most familiar with javascript, where I can type console.log() and see the output when I open up the console.

What's the equivalent of the web console for python?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to debug a django/python app is to place a breakpoint in the code

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

If you want to print a variable in the console, simply use the **print** function.

You can also **raise an Exception** or return an **HttpResponse** containing the variable.

Although, I strongly encourage you to use the breakpoint approach.